# Find max of ArrayList of ArrayList, key = length

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a ArrayList containing an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allChains = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I need to find out the max of these, key = length. In python I can do the same using below, how to do the same in Java.

```
>>> l = [ ["apple", "b", "c"], ["a"], ["a","b","c","d"]]
>>> max(l, key=len)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java 8 Streams :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allChains = new ArrayList<>();
allChains.add (new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList ("apple", "b", "c")));
allChains.add (new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList ("a")));
allChains.add (new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList ("a","b","c","d")));

ArrayList<String> longest = allChains.stream()
                                     .max(Comparator.comparingInt(ArrayList::size))
                                     .get();

System.out.println (longest);
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: Thx, also how to do the same in Java 7

Comment: @User see Rohit Jain's answer (using Collections.max). The Comparator would require more code compared to Java 8, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Collections#max(Collection, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)), and pass appropriate Comparator as second argument.

If you're using Java 8, you can use `Streams` also. The Comparator can be written as lambda:

```
(list1, list2) -> Integer.compare(list1.size(), list2.size());
```

In Java 7, it would be like this:

```
ArrayList<String> maxList = Collections.max(allChains, 
    new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
        public int compare(ArrayList<String> list1, ArrayList<String> list2) {
            return Integer.compare(list1.size(), list2.size());
        }
    });
```

Comment: The lambda expression is equivalent to ```(a, b) -> a.size() - b.size()```.

Comment: @saka1029 No, it's not. In case of overflows (which I understand is highly unexpected, and impossible in this case since size cannot be negative), it will fail.

Comment: OK. How about ```(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size())```.